# cocos2d-x 2.x CCScrollView getContentOffset always return Y is 0 when rescroll

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x, ccscrollview

I use 2.x cocos2d-x.
And I use CCScrollView.

I create new CCLayer extended class
and, add CCScrollView on the instance.

When I am scrolling, and I try to scroll again.
getContentOffset always show Y is 0.

```
void MyClass::scrollViewDidScroll(
    enter code here`CCScrollView* view) {
    CCLOG("%f", view->getContentOffset().y);
```

it always returns 0.0.

I added cell. and cell has button.
So, I make the CCControl size small.
But, I never had resolved.

Would you tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by myself.

I must set not only container's height bat also width larger than view size.

even if I set like this

```
setDirection(kCCScrollViewDirectionVertical)
```